# Kultura 3D 360 video playback

Tags: video, 360-virtual-reality

Anybody with any clues to the format required for Kultura 3D videos - side by side or over-under? and the resolution?

We have the monoscopic 360 working fine but not 3D

Or maybe Kultura does not support 3D?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The standard Kaltura Player documentation does not seem to offer any configuration or setting options for 'Stereoscopic' video, which is what I believe you are referring to here.

Many end devices and players will support either side-by-side or bottom-top stereoscopic formats.

Ideally the information would be signalled within the video itself - for example there is a proposal for a mp4 container metadata that includes a field or 'box' which allow this to be specified - see:

- https://github.com/google/spatial-media/blob/master/docs/spherical-video-v2-rfc.md#stereoscopic-3d-video-box-st3d

Some devices or players will allow the user configure manually the setting for given video, selecting either side-by-side or top-bottom.

If you have a device which you know supports one format but you can't play it via the Kaltura player, you can actually use the Kaltura video stream with other players by accessing the video URL's directly.

In other words you can get the HLS or MPEG-DASH video stream and use those in your player of choice - Kaltura provide information on accessing the stream directly here (at the time of writing):

- https://vpaas.kaltura.com/documentation/Deliver-and-Distribute-Media/how-retrieve-download-or-streaming-url-using-api-calls.html

(Note, I am assuming you mean Kaltura in all the above, rather than 'Kultura')